# QSerialPort readyRead() signal not working properly

Tags: c++, qt, arduino

So I am trying to let my Arduino communicate with my Qt project, but the signal readyRead() is never emitted by QSerialPort. I trial&error'ed many ways and orders to implement it, tried the code from the following video, which didn't work too, tried another microcontroller and another port.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AX-HhBXBzGg

I get the serial connection established with this code, so that my arduino's write-LED is blinking and its port is busy. I can only get readSerial() executed, when I use the function waitForReadyRead() periodically, which is dumb. Without that function readRead() does not get emitted.

Another observation: When I try to write something to my arduino, its read-LED is blinking, but it does not read the signal properly. With the Arduino IDE serial monitor it works fine.

Here is my Qt code and arduino code:

serial.h:

```
#ifndef SERIAL_H
#define SERIAL_H
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QDebug>

class Serial : public QSerialPort
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Serial();
    ~Serial();

public slots:
    void readSerial();
};

#endif // SERIAL_H
```

serial.cpp:

```
#include "serial.h"

Serial::Serial(){
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSerial()));
    setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    setReadBufferSize(10);

    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        if (info.description() == "Arduino Leonardo"){
            setPort(info);
            open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);
            if (isOpen()) qDebug() << portName();
        }
    }
}

Serial::~Serial(){
    if (isOpen()){
        close();
    }
}

void Serial::readSerial(){
    qDebug() << "Never triggered!";
    while (!atEnd()){
            QByteArray data = readAll();
            clear();
            qDebug() << data;
    }
}
```

arduino (kinda trivial):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(0);
  Serial.flush();
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is your Qt version?

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem using 5.13.1 and mingw (`readyRead()` fired only when calling `waitForReadyRead()`). Same code with 5.13.0 works. My solution was a periodic timer event (~50ms) which in turn executes `waitForReadyRead(1)`.

This is a known issue, documented [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-78086?jql=text%20~%20%22readyread%22).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll downgrade and try it again.

I also did it with a timer, but waitForReadyRead(0) did the job for me too, if you want to safe the 2% performance